# How does the getOutputStream method of the Process class work?

Tags: java, processbuilder

I'm studying the [ProcessBuilder](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html) class , and in there it says that one of the process attributes that each process builder manages is the following  :

> a source of standard input. By default, the subprocess reads input
> from a pipe. Java code can access this pipe via the output stream
> returned by Process.getOutputStream(). However, standard input may be
> redirected to another source using redirectInput. In this case,
> Process.getOutputStream() will return a null output stream, for which:
>
> - the write methods always throw IOException
> - the close method does  nothing

I then looked up the API function called [getOutputStream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html#getOutputStream--) , however it's still not clicking to m.

I don't get what they mean by the sentence :

> Output to the stream is piped into the standard input of the process
> represented by this Process object.

Just looking for clarification or possibly sample code about how this works. thanks

Answer (score 2):

This is a simple sample code.

```
public class ParentProcess {

    public static void main(String[] arags) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        Process p = new ProcessBuilder(
            "java", "-cp", "bin", "stackoverflow.ChildProcess").start();
        // receive from child
        new Thread(() -> {
            try {
                int c;
                while ((c = p.getInputStream().read()) != -1)
                    System.out.write((byte)c);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }).start();
        // send to child
        try (Writer w = new OutputStreamWriter(p.getOutputStream(), "UTF-8")) {
            w.write("send to child\n");
        }
        System.out.println("rc=" + p.waitFor());
    }

}

class ChildProcess {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        // receive from parent and send to parent
        System.out.println("child recevied: " + s.nextLine());
    }

}
```

Result is:

```
child recevied: send to child
rc=0
```